# Script not executed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've very little experience with weblanguages, so this may be a simple error.

I have a webpage with internal links as in `<a href="#div-id">button</a>`. However, due to a responsive bootstrap menu, scrolling sometimes overshoots. The problem is exactly as described in a previous question and I tried to implement the accepted solution:

[How can I use HTML ID links with the Bootstrap navbar-header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513853/how-can-i-use-html-id-links-with-the-bootstrap-navbar-header)

However, the suggested function is never executed. I have it implemented as follows. As a fool-proof way of testing, I have included two alert statements (one for an unrelated function). The first alert statement is properly executed, the second is never executed.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {                      // on document ready
    var div = $('#showOrHideDiv');   // cache <div>
    $('#action').click(function () { // on click on the `<a>`
        alert('here');               // => PROPERLY EXECUTED
        div.fadeToggle(1000);        // toggle div visibility over 1 second
    });
    // listen for click events originating from elements with href starting with #
    $('body').on('click.scroll-adjust', '[href^="#"]', function (e) {
      alert('here');                 // => NEVER EXECUTED
      var $nav;

      // make sure navigation hasn't already been prevented
      if ( e && e.isDefaultPrevented() ) return

      // get a reference to the offending navbar
      $nav = $('div.navbox')

      // check if the navbar is fixed
      if ( $nav.css('position') !== "fixed" ) return

      // listen for when the browser performs the scroll
      $(window).one('scroll', function () {
        // scroll the window up by the height of the navbar
        window.scrollBy(0, -$nav.height())
      });

    });
});

</script>
```

Can anyone point out the mistake in my implementation?

Comment: You never added click event ... Check the on syntax.

Comment: I just copy/past these scripts, I can't properly write them. But according to the comment (not mine), this should select all click events on links with `href`'s starting with an `#`? But I guess it isn't doing that. Any suggestion on how that should look?

Comment: It's written like .on("click", "a[href^='#']",function(e){

Comment: thanks! now the function is called for `<a href="#"></a>`, but not for `<a href="#div-id"></a>`. Is there anything like wildcards in these queries?

Comment: Actually... Your initial code works perfectly fine in fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/bwtum21a/1/

Are there any conflicting scripts ? Make sure your script is written just before closing body tag and after all the plugin scripts.

What I mean to say is like <script>[Your script]</script></body>

Comment: ah yes, that appears to be the problem. There is quite an elaborate "smoothscroll" script which is executed if the div actually exists. Maybe I can fix the original problem (the overshoot) once I understand that script, but that will take me a while.. so I'll get back to this question in a bit

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there were other functions being called that I wasn't aware of (thanks Jason for the hint). These scripts ensured smooth scrolling, which is a common feature of the type of templates I use, so it may be useful to give my solution here.

In the end I was able to fix the issue by adding a few lines to an existing function similar to the one I tried to implement myself.

Here is the new code, with comments where I added code:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);

  /* added by me: */
  var $x;
  var $nav;

  $nav = $('nav#tf-menu')

  if ( $nav.css('position') == "fixed" ){ $x=0; } else {$x=$nav.height()+30};
  /* end added */

  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({

      scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70 - $x //added the -$x
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
}
```